# How to use UIButton with Custom Class?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm currently working on an Application and my custom class doesn't seem to reflect on the UIButton even though I could select the class "RoundedButton". Here is the screenshot of my application:

[image: Appscreenshot]
here is the screenshot of the class name setting:

[image: class name setting]

and here is my code for the custom class:

```
class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let radius: CGFloat = self.bounds.size.height / 10.0
        self.layer.cornerRadius = radius
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

I've sifted through other sites but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Try using `self.layer.masksToBounds = true` instead of `clipsToBounds` on the view.

Comment: how are you loading/using the buttons? have you definitely set the class to the right thing?

Comment: I tried using self.layer.masksToBounds but it's still not working. @DV

Comment: Yes, I set the class to "Rounded Button" in the Identity Inspector of the UIButton. @Scriptable

Comment: can you take a screenshoot of class name setting

Comment: Edited post @Sh_Khan

Comment: last attempt is to create a github demo of this so i can check it

Comment: Have you tried adding the code inside `awakeFromNib()` method instead of `layoutSubviews()`?

Comment: I will give you one big recommendation. Don't create custom `UIButton` subclasses. Subclass `UIControl` instead. You will get everything that a `UIButton` has but with easier customization.

Answer (score 0):

I try your code and it works fine, Set your UIButton as Custom type

[image]

> Sometimes Xcode does not save the UIButton Custom Class correctly, try restarting Xcode and check if the class RoundedButton is still selected for that Button.